# Use smart pointer such as cv::Mat in std::queue

Tags: c++, std, smart-pointers

I want to store cv::Mat, which is a smart pointer along with other data structure in a queue.

I define a struct such as:

```
struct streamingData {
cv::Mat image;
int flag;
}
```

and define a queue such as:
std::queue q;

then push some data into the queue

I want to know if I call q.pop() to remove the first element, if the reference count of the cv::Mat decreases by 1?

Thanks a lot.

YL

Comment: _I want to know if I call q.pop() to remove the first element, if the reference count of the cv::Mat decreases by 1?_ This is a bit unclear. As long as your queue holds an instance of `cv::Mat` the counter cannot be less than 1. Do you want it to be removed from queue when every other reference has been lost? I cannot imagine that there is a notification for lost references (for performance reasons). But: If you pop an element from queue I would expect that the reference counter of popped element is decreased (and internal data deleted if ref. count was 1 before).

Comment: After having read a bit about `cv::Mat`, it appears to me that it can support "shared ownership of resource" as well as "view". The "shared ownership" uses reference counting to manage the release of resource (internal data) as soon as last owner is destroyed or overridden. (This is comparable to a `std::shared_ptr`.) The "view" can be achieved by e.g. using [`cv::Mat::Mat(Size, int, void*, size_t)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a9fa74fb14362d87cb183453d2441948f). This is **not** comparable to a `std::weak_ptr` because AFAIS it's not aware of "losing" it's data.

Comment: ... The "view" is rather like a raw pointer. Destroying the pointee can cause Undefined Behavior if the pointer is used for access afterwards.